# Standard ML function explanation

Tags: sml, ml

I'm kind of new to Standard ML and I have to write 2 functions, one of them has to find if an element exists in a list and the other one has to pick the first element from the same list if it matches the criteria from the first function.

So far I have come across this example:

```
fun contains _ [] = true
  | contains [] (x::xs) = false
  | contains ys (x::xs) = (mem ys x) andalso (contains ys xs)
```

and the example results are:

```
contains [1,2,3] [3,2]  (* returns true *)
contains [1,2,3] [3,2,3]  (* returns true *)
contains [1,2,3] [3,4,2]  (* returns false *)
```

I was tempted to use List.exists but I have to use recursion.
Can somebody explain what exactly is this function doing?
From what I understand, in the first line if the list is empty, it will return false, but the rest and the examples provided are not really clear to me. Also, what is the best approach for the second function, should I call the first one and if it returns true, just take the hd of the current list?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the second list is empty, the function returns true. If the first list is empty, it returns false (that case seems to be redundant unless `mem` is not properly defined for empty lists). If both lists are non-empty it returns true iff `mem ys x` is true and `contains ys xs` is true.

In other words this function is equivalent `List.forall` with `mem ys` as the predicate function.

Assuming that `mem ys x` returns true iff `x` is a member of `ys`, this means that `contains ys xs` returns true iff every member of `xs` is also a member of `ys`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you have any suggestions for the second function?